# Batch: Use variable multiple times in multiple for loops

Tags: batch-file, for-loop

In my batch file, I've got a couple of for loops.

```
exampleInputDir\weapon\%character%\thing1
                                  \thing2
                                  \thing3
```

Each of the thing# folders contains a motion.mtable file

```
FOR /R "C:\exampleInputDir\weapon\%character%\" %%G IN (motion.mtable) DO (
    FOR %%b in ("%%~dpG\.") DO set "weaponname=%%~nxb"
    FITD -le "%G%" -o "C:\exampleOutputDir\%character%\%weaponname%"
    )
```

If it isn't clear what I'm trying to do, I need the %G% variable more than once, and for one of those times, I need it slightly changed and put into another variable so I can call it twice in one command.

If something isn't clear just let me know and I'll try to clarify!
Thanks!

EDIT: I would like that last command to be:

```
FITD -le "exampleInputDir\weapon\%character%\thing#\motion.mtable" -o "C:\exampleOutputDir\%character%\thing#"
```

and i would like the command to run through thing1, thing2, and thing3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
FITD -le "%G%" -o "C:\exampleOutputDir\%character%\%%~nxb"
```

since `weaponname` and `%%~nxb` are intended to be the same.

You are falling into the `delayedexpansion` trap, like so many others. There are hundreds of examples on SO - just use the `search` facility.

---

You could also use `delayedexpansion` to solve the problem

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
FOR /R "C:\exampleInputDir\weapon\%character%\" %%G IN (motion.mtable) DO (
    FOR %%b in ("%%~dpG\.") DO set "weaponname=%%~nxb"
    FITD -le "%G%" -o "C:\exampleOutputDir\%character%\!weaponname!"
    )
endlocal
```

Using a `setlocal/endlocal` bracket to enable `delayedexpansion` and hence being able to access the *run-time* value of a variable modified within a `code block` (or parenthesised sequence of lines).

Advantages - allows access to the *run-time* value of a variable through `!var!` in place of `%var%` (`%var%` is resolved as the *parse-time* value)

Disadvantages - for the cognescenti
- values established or modified within the bracket survive only until the bracket ends
- The <kbd>!</kbd> has a modified meaning and needs special attention

Comment: Wait, the delayedexpansion trap? do I need delayedexpansion or not?
And thank you so much, i'll give it a go now :)